# Verification of contract using Brownie

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, contract-deployment, brownie

I'm at the point of a solidity course where I need to get the API key token from etherscan.io.

I followed all the steps, but my code breaks when I use Brownies deploy function with "publish_source".

`fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=False)`

and this is the error I get:

```
Transaction sent: 0xebb78b3dadcaac375f552f1352a32ec435f90ef75a02b10e6ced88133d53bf16
  Gas price: 1.447e-06 gwei   Gas limit: 397829   Nonce: 13
  FundMe.constructor confirmed   Block: 3881378   Gas used: 361663 (90.91%)
  FundMe deployed at: 0xAed87E48d5482b1de09AD0f54D18600BB216c640

  File "eth_brownie-1.19.3-py3.9.egg/brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "eth_brownie-1.19.3-py3.9.egg/brownie/project/scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 12, in main
    deploy_fund_me()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 7, in deploy_fund_me
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)
  File "eth_brownie-1.19.3-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/contract.py", line 552, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "eth_brownie-1.19.3-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/account.py", line 557, in deploy
    contract.publish_source(deployed_contract, silent=silent)
  File "eth_brownie-1.19.3-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/contract.py", line 411, in publish_source
    data = response.json()
  File "requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

I saw somewhere online that they said perhaps because I'm passing an empty variable, I've got the api key token in my .env file. I tried with wrap it in single quotes, double quotes and no quotes, still nothing.
I tried to F12 to go to source but it said "no definition found for publish_source"

Here is the full deploy code:

[image]

And I'm running in command line:

`brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network sepolia`

I tried googling for a solution but I couldn't find anything helpful.

If anyone has any advice or suggestions, I'd be super grateful! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you are using the correct explorer URL for Sepolia.

```
brownie networks add Ethereum sepolia host=https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID chainid=11155111 explorer=https://sepolia.etherscan.io/
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to double check to make sure its working correctly:

1. Run `brownie compile` to ensure most recent contract is compiled
2. Ensure environment variable in .env file is named `ETHERSCAN_TOKEN`
3. Make sure brownie is updated. Run `pip install eth-brownie -U`

When you've set this up correctly and run `brownie run deploy.py`, you'll see this message in the terminal.

```
Waiting for https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api to process contract...
Verification submitted successfully. Waiting for result...
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un error de actualizacion de brownie referente a los endpoints.
Debes verificar que el atributo explorer de la red este correctamente seteado
La url actual es https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api.

```
├─Sepolia (Infura)
  │ ├─id: sepolia
  │ ├─chainid: 11155111
  │ ├─explorer: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/
  │ ├─host: https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
  │ └─provider: infura
```

Usa el comando `brownie networks modify sepolia explorer=https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api`

```
SUCCESS: Network 'Sepolia (Infura)' has been modified
  └─Sepolia (Infura)
    ├─id: sepolia
    ├─chainid: 11155111
    ├─explorer: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api
    ├─host: https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
    └─provider: infura
```

Comment: This is an English only forum. Please, avoid using other languages.